# Double GET request from Gerrit Rest Api

Tags: python, gerrit

Im working on project with multiple request to Gerrit in python. I need two information about commits which are accessible by two different GET request

First one

`/changes/{change_id}/in`

Retrieves the branches and tags in which a change is included. I need to search for specific tag which is accessible by this request

Second one

`/changes/{commit_id}/revisions/{commit_current_revision}/files/{file}/diff`

Search for any changes to specific file in wanted revision

The problem is that, if I use both for one commit, time execution is ok. But when I use Second one for over 300 commits, it takes 20 seconds. When I add First one except Second, execution time grows to over 300 seconds.

Can I make such two request in one by AND logical statement?